# Gun control in Judaism

Tags: halacha, violence

In light of recent terrible acts committed that involved guns. What is the Torah perspective on gun control. Are there any Torah sources which discuss gun control from a halachic/hashkafic point of view. Is there such a value at all?

What I mean by gun control I mean to say the arguments given to curtail their proliferation or doubts regarding the right to own a gun as an inalienable right. Is there anything for such curtailing or against such curtailing in Halacha or Hashkafa?

***Given the nature of the question and the slim chance that Halachic books talk explicitly about gun control, answers may be personal opinioned but must be based off traditional Torah sources.***

Comment: Bava Batra 25 might be a good place to start: keeping nezikin out of cities. I doubt that there was any notion of "weapons control" per se in anything but modern times

Comment: Whether it's explicitly addressed or not, I don't see any reason to distinguish between a gun that is kept in a way that is hazardous in that context and any other hazard.

Comment: FYI http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arms_control#History

Comment: @Isaac Moses I think there is a difference. Guns come with safety locks and the like

Comment: In the recent resolution on ["Gun Violence in America"](http://www.rabbis.org/news/article.cfm?id=105804) by the Rabbinical Council of America, the only sources cited were a mishna indicating that guns shouldn't be glorified and a verse in Isaiah predicting a weapon-free Messianic age. If there was an explicit *Halachic* source in favor of gun control, they probably would have cited it.

Comment: @Nafkamina I'm not arguing about the details of each gun in its context. Some guns, stored in some ways, in some places, are hazardous. Some guns, stored in some ways, in some places, are safe. The former is likely treated by *Halacha* identically to other hazards.

Comment: Halachah dictates that a dog is required to be tied up, a pit open to the public is required to be public, an ox fenced, etc. A person is fully liable for damages incurred by his property if he doesn't guard it properly. If your minor child, due to your negligence, takes your gun and uses it to injure another, Beis Din may very well hold you liable for damages.

Comment: Could everyone write up proper answers instead o using the comment section of which I understand is not its purpose

Comment: http://www.torahcafe.com/rabbi-shlomo-yaffe/gun-control-a-halachic-exposition-video_be0e1b5bd.html

Comment: @menachem maybe you could summarize the gist of the class in an answer

Comment: @Nafkamina heh yeah, I think the reason folks are using the comments section, is because these *aren't* actually answers, only suggestions on where to look next

Comment: I know Rabbi Yaffe personally, much recommend

Comment: @nafkamina. I'd have to listen to it first

Comment: Is this a one-sided question? In other words, you are only interested in sources that go one way?

Comment: @Yishai no not at all. Anything at all is open

Comment: @Mefaresh, I made that explicit in the question, feel free to edit further if I didn't capture it.

Comment: I doubt that this has been addressed even in halachic sources as recent as a few hundred years ago because the entire concept of "gun rights" is really a very uniquely American concept. The rest of the world doesn't generally understand the American concept of "right to bear arms." It was granted as a right in America for very specific historical reasons that don't necessarily apply in other places. So "gun rights" hasn't been a thing to discuss earlier than the late 18th century. Because of the "gun rights" concept, gun control discussions in America are different from the rest of the world.

Comment: @Daniel agreed this my most recent edit allowing opinion based answers but based off of classical Torah sources

Comment: @Daniel, I read an article in a local paper (The Boston Globe) a few months ago which dealt with the framers' views on the subject. Apparently, the idea that the right to bear arms was not viewed as an "unalienable" (i.e. G-d-given) right, rather an et laasot.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt I'm just explaining why discussions about guns are different in the US (which I believe is the context in which the OP is framed) from what they are in other places. That is true regardless of the framers' opinions 250 years ago

Comment: Haven't listened to it recently, so I won't write an answer, but listen to [Rabbinic Perspectives on Gun Control](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/785985/_Daniel_Fridman/Rabbinic_Perspectives_on_Gun_Control)

Comment: The most recent issue of OU's Jewish Action magazine [has](https://www.ou.org/jewish_action/06/2016/gun-control-halachah/) two [pieces](https://www.ou.org/jewish_action/06/2016/should-i-carry-a-gun/) about guns in Halacha. They ought to form the basis of an answer here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch C.M. [409:3](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=cm_x11424) says:

> אסור לגדל כלב רע אא"כ הוא אסור בשלשלאות של ברזל וקשור בהם ובעיר הסמוכה לספר מותר לגדלו וקושרו ביום ומתירו בלילה
>
> It is forbidden to raise harmful dogs unless he chains them with iron chains. In a border town it is permitted to raise them and chain them by day and let them loose at night.

The Biurei HaGra explains this is limited to Israel, but the Ramo goes on to include the limitation outside if the dogs are potentially harmful to people. The purpose of putting them in chains (in the latter case) includes preventing them from scaring pregnant women (מאירת עינים there), so the chaining has to be obvious, not just effective.

The analogy to gun control seems fairly obvious. Permitted for self defense, even in ways which have some theoretical possibility of harm (at night in a border town), but otherwise precautions must be taken to prevent accidental harm to others. There was, however, no decree to outright ban them.

In addition, in terms of sales (analogous to background check requirements, I guess) [Avoda Zarah 15b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=15b&format=pdf) says it is forbidden to sell, make or fix weapons for someone (Jewish or not) who one is concerned will use it for murder.

In terms of "inalienable rights" Judaism doesn't have (to my knowledge) any Halachic or Hashkafic approach which worries about Government encroachment and tyranny. However, one of the rights recently recognized in the second amendment is self defense (the recent DC vs. Heller decision), and this is recognized in Judaism not as a right but as an obligation, about oneself as well as in defense of others. ([Sanhedrin 72a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=72&format=pdf) and [73a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=73&format=pdf) respectively).

Some of these same sources and additional ones are discussed in [this article](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/507002/jewish/What-Does-Judaism-Say-About-Gun-Control.htm) by Rabbi Shlomo Yaffe and he uses them to apply some thoughts to gun control, including the Ramban on Bereishis 4:20 which discusses the "guns (swords) don't kill people, people kill people" slogans you hear every once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article based on the Torah's perspective here:

http://www.koshertorah.com/PDF/beararms2011.pdf

This article shows how the Jews had to be armed to protect themselves as needed. Consider the fact that while rebuilding the Temple, they had to have armed guards at all times and all the workers had to carry weapons.. [Nechemiah 4:10 - 16](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16511#showrashi=true)

The significant quote from the article is

> I   learn   from   religious   sources   and   moral   example   that 
>   it   is   the   absolute   right   of   every individual to be able to
>   protect him/herself against every real threat that they may possibly
>   be exposed to.  I believe it is the moral obligation of every citizen
>   of every country, anywhere, to bear arms, or to have at his/her
>   disposal any and all types of self defense tools that may be needed at
>   a moment's notice.

Comment: @DoubleAA I edited in the conclusion summary from the article along with the pointer to Nechemiah.

Comment: There is very little in that article that is based on Torah sources, and almost nothing based on Halachah. Furthermore, this article does not discuss (though it attempts, in my opinion badly, to imply) applicability from these sources to gun control. The sources are mostly about national defense and warfare, with a snippet (really only an allusion without direct quotation) about self defense.