# Is one allowed to carry a gun for self-defense if local secular law prohibits it?

Tags: halacha, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, dina-dmalchusa-dina

There is a rule of *Dina D'Malchuta Dina* - the law of the land is valid, providing that it does not conflict directly with Torah laws.

There is a Torah law of *Venishmartem lenafshotechem* (Devarim 4:15), that one must do what he can to guard his own life. Certainly, when one knows that someone is about to kill him, he is allowed to defend himself and use his gun to kill the other.

Gun control laws vary widely around the world. Supposing someone is unable to obtain a gun legally in his location, would he be permitted to carry a gun illegally for self-defense purposes if he is in a Pikuach Nefesh situation (ex. he needs to travel through Pikuach-Nefesh-dangerous locations)?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55269/gun-control-in-judaism

Comment: It seems that the controlling factor here would be the precise circumstances. If we can evaluate the circumstances and determine that carrying a gun is the only way to prevent an unambiguous threat to your life, it would seem obvious that Halacha would require you to carry a gun. If that determination can't be made, then it's a much more complicated call. I suspect that there are few places in the US in which the danger is that clear. For example, in NY, carrying an unlicensed gun could get a person arrested, and jail time could get a person killed, so the danger goes both ways.

Comment: If traveling through those dangerous neighborhoods unarmed is real Pikuach Nefesh, then it is _forbidden_ to do so, no?

Comment: @IsaacMoses like DoubleAA, you've raised a very valid point, and I don't have any rebuttal. Your last comment approaches a credible answer, though, since you mentioned that there may be *piku'ach nefesh* being in jail. One point to that, though. In court, if proven that you killed in self-defense, you are innocent of murder charges. Gun possession - I don't know. Of course, without a prev. criminal record, you might not be jailed. Then again, Bernie Goetz was jailed for quite a while.

Comment: The more I think about it, the less I can believe that there are any places in the US where it's unambiguously *pikuach nefesh* to go without a gun, and where it's unambiguously not *pikuach nefesh* to go with one (licensed or not). As @DoubleAA said, if your commute case was serious, it would be forbidden for you to do that commute now, and your self-preservation drive wouldn't let you do it. On the flip side, if you go into a real war zone with a gun, you're still in a war zone. In fact, you may make yourself less likely to be robbed at the expense of being more likely to get shot.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, you are allowed to go into dangerous situations for work, like climbing trees and the like. A bad commute seems no worse than that.

Comment: @Yishai examples abound - pediatricians, infectious disease doctors, cops, firemen, army ...

Comment: AFAIK, there is significant research correlating violent incidents with gun carriage (in the US at least). So if anything, it would be pikuach nefesh to **not** carry a gun with you.

Comment: Wow, I thought by now it should have shown up.  I apologize for my misstatement.  I'll move your conversation to chat.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the conversation between JJLL and DanF has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32114/discussion-on-question-by-danf-is-one-allowed-to-carry-a-gun-for-self-defense-if).

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Possibly. Though, for most people, it's better than being dead or injured. In many court cases, from what I have heard, people carrying an illegal gun who have used it in self-defense are not jailed. This is esp. true if they have no prior criminal record.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I have been living in europe for many years. I believe that no civilian is legally able to carry a gun in public at all, ever. Only guns for hunting can be registered and used only for hunting, re rgistering each season. To my knowledge handguns arent allowed at all, so civilians in europe, and attacks do occur monthly here, are unable to defend themselves at all. No wonder european jewish population is falling.

Comment: @gamliela "No wonder European Jewish population is falling" I agree with you, somewhat, on that. But ant-Semitism in Europe is on the rise, and, I think we can figure out which demographic group is largely responsible for that :) If it's not guns, they use cars, knives and bombs, and a gun won't protect you against 2 of those. Best discussion I heard on radio was "If more Jews had armed themselves in 1942, perhaps, many more million might have been saved." I don't know if every European country has the same gun ban, though. You imply that they all do. Is this true?

Comment: A wikapedia article Overview of gun laws of countries says Italy allows handguns, in spain proof of need for self defence allows one. Germany and france ar more strict, definitely not like usa. We are in small town spain, there ar a lot of morrocans and various others of that religion. It seems friendly and calm. Spanish dont befriend at all but certain habits of tolerance, the mask, keep outright antagonism hidden. In eu terrorism happens incities, its been discovered preparation sometimes carried out in small towns or suburbs. c. 1492 shows even with arms its not so good. idk atm which is.

Comment: @gamliela "c. 1492" - Did you mean this? I mentioned 1942 in my comment. In light of your mentioning 1492, it's interesting to discover that Spain is more "calm" now in comparison to other countries. Though, I understand that in the past few years, anti Semitism has been on a sharp rise.

Comment: 1942, 1492, both bad. I was just thinking that in 1492  jews were armed and it didn't stop the exile then it became the antisemitism against converts who stayed. Spain decided to give free citizenship to Sephardim in 2015. I doubt there will be many takers. Its not so much antisemitism directly these days, its just so much modern catholic spanishness imo. We havent been here very long. we may be able to find a niche or we willmove on.

Answer (score -2):

The Gemara in Nedarim 28a says:

> והאמר שמואל דינא דמלכותא דינא
>
> Didn't Shmuel say "the law of the land is the law"?

It seems that the law of the land is considered law (I assume as long as it does not conflict with the practice of Torah Judaism). See also Gittin 10b.

Comment: Oh my! You're really trying to grab my attention on my "old" question, here! You have a deleted answer, and this one seems very similar to the deleted one. I'm not convinced that it would apply in this case in all situations, though. Re-read my 2nd paragraph, please. There is a general rule that when the local law conflicts a Torah law, one abides by Torah law. Here, it's a question of whether *Venishmartem lenafshotechem * is an actual mitzvah than can be applied based on either one's perception or if one constantly walks in (commutes) where there is a high chance of being killed.

Comment: I see three issues at play here: One, does Dina d'malchusa even applyapplies in this scenario (it doesn't apply across the board, and it's a machlokes in the poskim as to where we do apply it)? Two, in the event that it does, does ushemartem es nafshoseichem override Dina d'malchusa? Three, in the event that it does, does it make a difference that the chiyuv can be carried out in other ways, such as carrying a knife. Just posting an answer stating there is a rule called Dina d'malchusa - a concession given in the OP - does not do this complex topic nearly enough justice.

Comment: @DonielF ..And, as stated, he repeated the answer that was deleted. I'm really puzzled.

Comment: @ezra Just trying to grab your attention, here. In case you want to modify your answer. See my 1st comment as a reminder.